# AngularJS - Call Javascript function(s) using Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, vlc

When an video url is clicked, I am using below directive to append html and invoke VLC object

```
myApp.directive('vlcObject', function ($compile, $rootScope,$timeout) {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var vlcPlayerTemplate =
                '<object id="vlc" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" class="vlc" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" width="100%" height="100%">' +
                '    <param name="Src" value="SomeUrl"></param>' +
                '    <param name="autoplay" value="true" ></param>' +
                '    <param name="toolbar" value="false"></param>' +
                '    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="vlcfirefox" autoplay="yes" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" target="SomeUrl"></embed>' +
            '</object>';
            element.html(vlcPlayerTemplate);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });        
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker
    };
});
```

**Calling Directive via Service**

```
this.startVLCPlayerAt = function (pictureboxIndex) {
    angular.element(
        document.querySelector('#StreamingArea' + pictureboxIndex)
    ).append($compile("<vlc-object></vlc-object>")($rootScope));
};`
```

Now I want to include/call JavaScript functions along with directive, so when url is clicked, two things will happen

1. 1) Append VLC object HTML
2. 2) Call below JS function and create VLC playlist and perform
   required operations

**JS Functions**

```
function getVLC(name)
{
    if( window.document[name] )
    {
        return window.document[name];
    }
    if( navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1 )
    {
        if( document.embeds && document.embeds[name] )
            return document.embeds[name];
    }
    else
    {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
}

function registerVLCEvent(event, handler)
{
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

    if( vlc )
    {
        if( vlc.attachEvent )
        {
            // Microsoft
            vlc.attachEvent(event, handler);
        }
        else if( vlc.addEventListener )
        {
            // Mozilla: DOM level 2
            vlc.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        }
    }
}

function unregisterVLCEvent(event, handler)
{
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

    if( vlc )
    {
        if( vlc.detachEvent )
        {
            // Microsoft
            vlc.detachEvent(event, handler);
        }
        else if( vlc.removeEventListener )
        {
            // Mozilla: DOM level 2
            vlc.removeEventListener(event, handler, false);
        }
    }
}

function doGo(targetURL)
{
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

    if( vlc )
    {
        vlc.playlist.items.clear();
        var options = [":rtsp-tcp"];
        var itemId = vlc.playlist.add(targetURL,"",options);
        if( itemId != -1 )
        {
            // play MRL
            vlc.playlist.playItem(itemId);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("cannot play at the moment !");
        }
    }
}
```

Subsequently, when user clicks on play/pause button, I am using below functions to perform the same action

```
<input type="button" id="PlayOrPause" style="width:60px" value="Play" onClick='doPlayOrPause();'>
<input type="button" value="Stop" onClick='doStop();'>

function doPlayOrPause()
    {
        var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
        if( vlc )
        {
            if( vlc.playlist.isPlaying )
                vlc.playlist.togglePause();
            else
                vlc.playlist.play();
        }
    }

    function doStop()
    {
        var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
        if( vlc )
            vlc.playlist.stop();
    }
```

How do I call the above JS functions using directive ?

Comment: You should create a controller for your directive and include any behaviour you need within it. Also, you should probably use the `template` option for your directive rather than updating the HTML manually.

Comment: Calling directive via service like `this.startVLCPlayerAt = function (pictureboxIndex) {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#StreamingArea' + pictureboxIndex)).append($compile("<vlc-object></vlc-object>")($rootScope));
};` Also how do I call JS functions from controller ? Could  you post it as an answer related to this question